# C#/ Visual Studio not showing umlauts properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encoding, windows-phone

I am downloading an XML-File via WebClient like this:

```
WebClient connect = new WebClient();
connect.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(connect_DownloadStringCompleted);
connect.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://conn.info/api/v8/search/item_short.xml?apikey=123&lang=de&q="+textBox1.Text));
```

Then I parse them

```
XElement erg = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
```

but the problem is, that German letters like "ü" or "ä" won't be displayed properly.
Instead, I get a "?" for each of these letters in my output (on a windows phone device).

How is this solvable?

Comment: I think you would need something like `connect.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: Why is this tagged/titled with "Visual Studio"? You aren't *displaying* the XML within Visual Studio.

Comment: What does `int cp = (new WebClient()).Encoding.CodePage;` yield? Depending on the web site, maybe you need `connect.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);` instead.

Comment: I can see the umlauts written correctly in the debug-console, but not on the Windows Phone device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume here that the encoding of your XML is ISO-8859-1. (I cannot access the domain you have above in your code). Try to set the encoding as follows:

```
connect.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

I tested a piece of code with http://www.spiegel.de/thema/windows_phone_8/index.rss and it works for me. Please find a screenshot of the results. I circled for you the words with the special characters from the German language.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already noted that umlauts are missing.
I would suggest setting your WebClient to UTF8 mode:

```
connect.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: are the umlauts still in the received xml before it gets parsed or already missing? Is the issue only occuring on the mobile device?

Comment: It is only occuring on the mobile device

Comment: out of curiousity (since a german social.msdn... discussion had the same topic) is it working while using a mobile network (not wlan/lan)

Comment: The problem still occurs, even when I am on a cellular network.
I found something interesting: a lot of "ö"-chars are shown properly, but others are not. As if there were different ö-values.